# Is there a couchdb java client that uses Gson?

Tags: java, couchdb

I've had great luck storing my Java objects into Memcached using Google's JSON libraries (Gson).   I can take any Java object, serialize it with Gson then cache it in Memcached.  Later I can get the JSON out of memcached and deserialize it to the same type of object.

I want to do something very similar for couchdb.  Couchdb stores documents as Json, so I'd think I could find a couchdb client that has stores and gets documents like this:

```
couchdb.storeDocument("user12345", myAppUser);
MyAppUser user = couchdb.getDocument("user12345", MyAppUser.class);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ektorp: http://ektorp.org/

Is based on Jackson but provides raw access aswell:
in org.ektorp.CouchDbConnector:

```
InputStream getAsStream(String s)

InputStream queryForStream(ViewQuery query);
```

That said, I don't see any good reason NOT to use the methods that map to objects in most cases:

```
<T> T get(Class<T> c, String id);
```

Answer (score 3):

I found one that works exactly like I was hoping!

LightCouch from http://www.lightcouch.org/

Here is the javadoc for the client
http://www.lightcouch.org/javadocs/org/lightcouch/CouchDbClient.html
it has the following methods:

```
   <T> T find(Class<T> classType, String id)
   Response save(Object object)
```

Comment: Make sure to see how this is implemented: whether by using a databinding lib (most likely), or implement custom scheme (correctness of which I would not count on, given it's pre-alpha version...)

Comment: Just little note, it's versions is GA.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access data as either Strings or byte[]s, and then use a Java JSON library (another good one is [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org)) to bind on that. There is no strict need for the two part to be closely coupled.

Comment: Is there a couchdb client that can return the raw strings or byte[]s?  There are about 10 couchdb clients for Java and the ones I've looked through tend to have some object mapping built in.  I didn't notice methods for getting and setting raw data.  I certainly don't mind doing the serialization and de-serialization myself, I'm already doing it for memcached.

Comment: I think so; the other answer mentioned Ektorp which seems like a really good client... so maybe I should change my answer. :-)